# Данные через segue программно

Tags: xcode, ios, ios7

Всем привет! Кто-нибудь знает, как можно с Custom Cell (который я создаю программно) в  UIСollectionViewController,  отправить данные в другое контроллер (с помощью segue)?  Про вариант перетягивать с Cell на другой контроллер руками знаю, но хотелось бы услышать, как это сделать программно. Программно получается, чтобы другой контроллер появлялся в Navigation Controller,  а вот значения не ставятся. Пробовал уже делать даже через синглтон, чтобы наверняка был один инстанс, но что-то не прокатило...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Программно с segue:

перетягиваем из UICollectionViewController (а не его ячеек) segue на нужный UIViewController
назваем как-то segue ("DetailsVC")
в методе `collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:` пишем

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"DetailsVC"];
```

реализуем метод

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
   if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"DetailsVC"]) {
        MySecondVC *vc = segue.destinationViewController;
        /* тут конфигурим наш UIViewController с нужным объектом, например так:
        if ([[self.collectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems] count]) {
             NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.collectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems][0];
             MyItem *item = self.items[indexPath.item];
             vc.item = item;
        }
        */
   }
}
```

Также можно обойтись и без segue, для этого вам нужно будет задать в storyboard "storyboard id" для вашего второго UIViewController далее

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     MySecondVC *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"your_second_vc_id_here"];
    MyItem *item = self.items[indexPath.item];
    vc.item = item;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, но уже пробовал этот способ. Забыл сказать, что у меня segue.destinationViewController в  prepareForSegue равен  nil description.  Как так может быть? я ведь перетягивал на него segue

Comment: Если вы вдруг забыли, убедитесь, что хэндлите именно ту segue (по identifier). Если все с ним ок, проверьте откуда куда она следует на сториборде, попробуйте ее удалить и протянуть заново. От UIViewController (желтого значка внизу) удерживая ctrl пететащите к другому UIViewController в любой место на его view. Если выделить segue подсвечиваются также и оба UIViewCotroller к ней привязанные - посмотрите что подвечивается то, что нужно

Comment: Да, я делал несколько раз. Даже в   outlets меню смотрел. Исходящая ссылка указывает на дочерний, в дочернем root  указывает на родителя. И смешно,  и плакать хочется. :)

Comment: Вроде и регистрирую сам cell, как
 [self.collectionView registerClass:[SaleCell class]
            forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"SaleCell"];

Comment: А  значения в  prepareForSegue можно и outlet-ам ставить (пример  UILabel), может они не обновляются? Или вначале в свойство значение, потом в viewWillAppear обновить UILabel

Comment: если вы работаете со сториборд, зачем вам registerClass:forCellWithResuseIdentifier: ?